# Why can't I overload this comparator that I pass to std::upper_bound

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I am fairly new to C++ and thought it was always ok to overload functions, by overloading I mean:

> Function overloading in C++ You can have multiple definitions for the same function name in the same scope. The definition of the function must differ from each other by the types and/or the number of arguments in the argument list. You can not overload function declarations that differ only by return type.

However when I write the code bellow it does not compile, and I have the impression that std::upper_bound cannot resolve which comparator it should use, though it would appear easy as there is only one that has a correct signature.

**EDIT** Those functions are in a utility file (not class) in a namespace.

***I did this following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226489/organising-utility-functions-in-c)***

I am likely totally wrong here, can you explain

1. why the code does not compile
2. how I could write 2 implementation of lt which different signature that will have the code compiling and runnable

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>

//I have a utility file where functions are defined in a namespace
namespace util{
  bool lt(double y, const std::pair<double, long>& x) { 
      return x.first < y;
  }
  //If this function is commented the whole will compile and run
  bool lt(const std::pair<double, long>& x, double y) {
      return x.first < y;
  }
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::pair<double,long> > v;
  v.push_back(std::make_pair(999., 123));
  v.push_back(std::make_pair(100., 3));
  v.push_back(std::make_pair(15., 13));
  v.push_back(std::make_pair(10., 12));
  v.push_back(std::make_pair(1., 2));
  //use upper_bound
  std::vector<std::pair<double,long> >::iterator it =
      std::upper_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 25., util::lt);
  std::cout << " it->first => " << it->first << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `std::upper_bound` is *templated* on the type of the predicate (the function you are passing), the particular overload to be used has to be known *before* any of the body of `upper_bound` is looked at (which is where overload resolution could be carried out, since the arguments are known). There are various ways around this, none of them particularly pretty:

- cast to the exact type:

  ```
  std::upper_bound(v.begin, v.end(), 25.0, static_cast<bool (*)(double, const std::pair<double, long>&>(lt))
  ```
- Wrap the call in a lambda:

  ```
  [](auto x, auto y){ return lt(x, y); }
  ```
- Put the functions inside a class, so that the template is instantiated with the type of the class, then overload resolution happens inside the body of the template:

  ```
  struct LT {
      bool operator()(double y, const std::pair<double, long>& x) {
          return x.first < y;
      }
      bool operator()(const std::pair<double, long>& x, double y) {
          return x.first < y;
      }
  };
  // ...
  std::upper_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 25.0, LT());
  ```

Note that the second 2 options are *almost* the same thing!

---

As it is, I would suggest you stop and think about what you are doing. Does it really make sense to provide ordering between two entirely different types? And your first function actually seems to be implement `gt` (greater than), maybe it was supposed to be `return y < x.first;`?

I also really consider using [`endl`](http://chris-sharpe.blogspot.co.uk/2016/02/why-you-shouldnt-use-stdendl.html) to be a bad practice (I know not everyone agrees with me).

Comment: Great ! I like last option. I have a "utility" file and from what I understand I can almost replace the "namespace" by class or struct, to make it a utility class and it will work ! I was doing this because of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226489/organising-utility-functions-in-c

Comment: `namespace`s often make more sense for grouping utilities, but yes, this is one reason why you might choose a class (with non-`static` member functions).

Answer (score 3):

The place where you call `upper_bound` is not a call site for `lt`, so no overload resolution is taking place here, and your overloads are ambiguous.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

bool lt(const std::pair<double, long>& x, const std::pair<double, long>& y)
{
    return x.first < y.first;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<double, long>> v;
    v.push_back(std::make_pair(999., 123));
    v.push_back(std::make_pair(100., 3));
    v.push_back(std::make_pair(15., 13));
    v.push_back(std::make_pair(10., 12));
    v.push_back(std::make_pair(1., 2));
    // use upper_bound
    std::vector<std::pair<double, long>>::iterator it =
        std::upper_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), std::make_pair(25., 0.), lt);
    std::cout << " it->first => " << it->first << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Ok, this answers 1. is there a way to answer 2 ?

Comment: You can wrap them in a callable - either functor or labmda.